# p values all = 1 from glht Tukey following negative binomial glmm

Tags: p-value, lme4-nlme, tukey-hsd-test

I have an issues with corrected p values from glht Tukey. When I use adjusted p values using the Holm method all p values = 1. If I do not adjust p values the issue goes away. 
I'v trawled online but can't find a useful solution to my problem.

Reproducible code is:

```
library (lme4)
library(glht)
act<-glmer.nb(Abundance~Treatment*Contacts+(1|Site),data=y) 
Anova(act)
summary(glht(act,linfct=mcp(Treatment="Tukey")),test=adjusted(type="holm"))

y<-structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("C", 
"HS", "LS", "U"), class = "factor"), Site = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("G", "I", "M"), class = "factor"), Contacts = c(522, 
457.7, 390.6, 341.9, 421.8, 375.1, 523.7, 591.9, 514.7, 307.7, 
354.5, 201, 178.3, 144.1, 129.4, 188.4, 232.5, 298.6, 134, 122.1, 
108.7, 226.1, 212.7, 228.2, 257.9, 264.3, 364.4, 90.9, 110.2, 
94.7, 129, 113.5, 123.6, 121.6, 109.4, 92.3), Abundance = c(32L, 
54L, 34L, 79L, 161L, 108L, 66L, 88L, 97L, 98L, 96L, 142L, 202L, 
161L, 209L, 315L, 187L, 78L, 64L, 68L, 50L, 125L, 216L, 233L, 
80L, 130L, 89L, 1L, 0L, 5L, 13L, 34L, 79L, 58L, 14L, 108L)), .Names =     c("Treatment", 
"Site", "Contacts", "Abundance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

R output for Anova is:

```
> Anova(act.nb)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II Wald chisquare tests)

Response: Abundance
                 Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
Treatment          44.1059  3  1.433e-09 ***
Contacts            0.4510  1     0.5019    
Treatment:Contacts  0.5332  3     0.9115    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

and for Tukey is:

```
>     summary(glht(act,linfct=mcp(Treatment="Tukey")),test=adjusted(type="holm"))

         Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: glmer(formula = Abundance ~ Treatment * Contacts + (1 | Site), 
    data = y, family = negative.binomial(theta = 3.33457338860666))

Linear Hypotheses:
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
HS - C == 0   -1.5663     1.7823  -0.879        1
LS - C == 0    0.2386     0.9937   0.240        1
U - C == 0    -0.4121     1.4301  -0.288        1
LS - HS == 0   1.8049     1.7571   1.027        1
U - HS == 0    1.1543     2.2087   0.523        1
U - LS == 0   -0.6506     1.4050  -0.463        1
(Adjusted p values reported -- holm method)

Warning message:
In mcp2matrix(model, linfct = linfct) :
  covariate interactions found -- default contrast might be inappropriate
```

Comment: This isn't an R help site. For the rest of us, what does `glht` do, please?

Comment: I think there is a genuine statistical question here about what happens when you adjust for multiple comparisons.

Comment: @mdewey I would like to believe that but the question style doesn't make it easy for non-R users to understand.

Comment: glht is a package used in R to compute Tukey on glmm results. The question was meant to be statistical but I was preempting the inevitable comment of included methods of analysis and reproducible code. Apologies for the distress this caused.

Comment: Thanks for the detail. No distress here; just a preference for clarity over obscurity.

Answer (score 1):

If you take your most extreme $z$ of 1.027 and work out the probability of exceeding this in absolute value using `pnorm` you will find a value approximately 0.3. If you were using Bonferroni this would be multiplied by 6, the number of comparisons, and I suspect that in Holm although the calculations are more complex you would also get adjusted $p$ values greater than 1 which `glht` reports as 1.

By the way trying to interpret main effects in the presence of interactions is hazardous as `glht` helpfully warns you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mdewey. I suspected this may be the case. I think I'll try the GLMM without the interaction too.